# undefined constructor in array of objects

Tags: constructor, undefined

I would like to create an array of objects to put through a loop. I have created the constructor and declared the array of objects properly but I get an error stating "the constructor is undefined"

```
public class TaxPayer 
{
    int social;
    double salary;

    TaxPayer(int soc, double sal)
    {
        social = soc;
        salary = sal;
    }
    public int getSocial() {
        return social;
    }
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
}
```

and then...

```
public class TaxPayerTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x;
        TaxPayer[] tax = new TaxPayer[10];

        for(x = 0; x<10 ; x++)
        {

            **tax[x] = new TaxPayer(9999,"0");**
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }
}
```

Bolded line produces the error stating the TaxPayer constructor is undefined.

Any comments?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor is defined as `int , double` buy you using it like this

```
tax[x] = new TaxPayer(9999,"0")
```

This is `int , String` which is not defined.

You should use it like this:

```
tax[x] = new TaxPayer(9999,0)
```